# What is this JS syntax? Assignment in expression? (x != null && (y = x))

Tags: javascript, syntax, conditional-statements

I'm working with this JS plugin, and I've encountered some syntax I've never seen before. I understand what it's doing, but I'm not sure why it works.

Here's an example of one instance of it:

```
settings.maxId != null && (params.max_id = settings.maxId);
```

Is this just taking advantage of conditionals and the single = ? Is this common syntax for JS?

Comment: hey this seems to be poor code - (!=) means not equal and checking if object is not null and the second condition (=) means assignment - I wonder why it is used in conditional statement in this instance. Cheers!

Comment: @Tats_innit: Where's the conditional statement? This code is perfectly valid; it's just silly.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit  Hiya Srry man I presumed **conditional** because it uses not null check, thanks and srry if I am wrong - Ah cool so its not just me it is actually a bad statement then! Cheers

Comment: i remember this coding style was popular in ANSI C for reading a file: while (nextChar = file.readLine()), but i dont think i have seen it since because it is an excellent anti-pattern.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In JavaScript the `=` operator is an *expression* and evaluates the assigned value. Because it is an *expression* it can be used anywhere an expression is allowed *even though it causes a side-effect*.
Thus:

```
settings.maxId != null && (params.max_id = settings.maxId)
```

Means: If `settings.maxId` is not null then (*and only then*, since `&&` is [short circuiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)) evaluate the right-expression (`params.max_id = settings.maxId`) which in turn causes the value of `settings.maxId` to be assigned to `params.max_id`.
This is *much more clearly* written as:

```
if (settings.maxId != null) {
  params.max_id = settings.maxId
}
```

Happy coding.

Answer (score 3):

this statement will assign `params.max_id = settings.maxId` only if `settings.maxId != null` due to the fact that `&&` is a short-circuit logic operator

this behaviour is due to the fact that javascript will evaluate the condition until it's necessary. thus, if first condition is false and the second is in `AND` there's no need to check further

Answer (score 3):

The `&&` operator is known as "boolean `AND`". Typically, you'd see it in an `if` statement:

```
if (x == true && y == false) {
```

but that's not a restriction. You may use it in any valid expression to "combine" the boolean values of its operands into a single boolean result, according to the logical "AND" operation:

```
var z = (x == true && y == false);
// z is now true or false, accordingly
```

One of the lovely things about `&&` is that it "short circuits". In `false && true`, because the first operand is `false` the entire expression may only evaluate to `false`, so the second operand is not even evaluated.

Let's check that again:

```
var z = (false && foo());
// z is now false
```

In this statement, the function `foo` is never even called! It doesn't have to be, for the program to know that `z` will be `false.`

This is more than an optimisation — you can rely on it.

Some silly people use this technique to rewrite conditional statements:

```
if (x == 0) {
   foo();
}
```

into hard-to-read single expressions:

```
(x == 0) && foo();
```

Now, consider that assignment can be an expression just like a function call:

```
var a = (b = c);
```

Or:

```
var a = (b = foo());
```

And add in a conditional via the above technique:

```
var a = ((x == 0) && (b = foo()));
```

Now the entire expression `b = foo()` won't be evaluated at all if `x` is not `0`, because of short circuiting.

We don't even need to do anything with the result of the `&&` operation, and if we don't store it to `a` you're left with just:

```
(x == 0) && (b = foo());
```

which is a statement that'll assign `b` to the value of `foo()` only if `x` is `0`.

Avoid it. It's hard to read. Just use an `if` statement.